# Determine which Avada Fusion Builder Elements are being used on a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to determine which Fusion Builder Elements are being currently used on a WordPress site?

I have a lot of the elements enabled for a site I'm working on, and I'd like to disable the ones I don't need.  Problem is, it's a full site I've taken on from another developer and I REAAAALLY don't want to have to scour the entire site and check for potentially broken elements every time I disable something.

Is this a functionality somewhere within Avada I'm completely missing and I can't find documented anywhere?

I was thinking of writing a tiny plugin that checks the `wp_posts` table and searching for `[fusion_xxxx]` elements and displaying a list of used builder elements.  Then I can determine which are used throughout the site.
Is this a bad time for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that will run a query on the DB and display used elements and the number of times each is used.  Simple, but I **think** it gets the job done.  I very-well might be missing something very obvious about how the info is stored.

This is done in an ajax call, displayed in the browser in a formatted list, etc.

Anywho, here's the part of the plugin that actually gathers the info:

```
protected function getElementsFromTable($table, $field, &$element_collection)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE `" . $field . "` LIKE '%[/fusion_%';";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    foreach ($results as $item) {
        preg_match_all("/\[\/fusion_(.+?)\]/", $item->{$field}, $elements);

        // No results found, bail!
        if (!count($elements[1])) {
            continue;
        }

        // Store the results
        foreach ($elements[1] as $element) {
            if (!array_key_exists('fusion_' . $element, $element_collection)) {
                $element_collection["fusion_" . $element] = 1;
            } else {
                $element_collection["fusion_" . $element]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

arsort($element_collection);
```

Usage:

`$this->getElementsFromTable("wp_posts", "post_conent", $element_collection);`